# Implement options menu in Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, options-menu

I have two fragment activities and one fragment. Here's how the app logic looks like:

```
FragmentActivity A ==> Fragment B ==> FragmentActivity C.
```

FragmentActivity A is the parent activity of fragment B and has an options menu that shows correctly.Fragment B contains a listview. When a list item is clicked on fragment B,its details are displayed in FragmentActivity C.Now i want to display an options menu inside C in the actionBar.However, the menu is only displayed after the menu button is clicked.I want it as an actionbar action.

Here is the code for Activity C:

```
public class LatestDetailsFragment extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnItemClickListener {

public LatestDetailsFragment() {
    photoImages = new ImageItem();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_latestdetails);

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    // setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.details_fragment_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.contact:
        ContactOwnerFragment contactFragment = new ContactOwnerFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        contactFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        contactFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "contact");
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And the menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="be.hcpl.android.example.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/contact"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_call"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/contact"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
</item>
```

I cannot use `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` on the activity because it raises an error,I don't know why. I want to display an icon on the actionbar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `menu.clear()` before inflating menus.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
menu.clear();
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.details_fragment_menu, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

From the [Documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#clear())

> public abstract void clear () Remove all existing items from the menu, leaving it empty as if it had just been created.